# Image Literals, Arrays and randomizing in Swift. Why does this method work but the other doesn't

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Creating a dice roll app following Angela Yu's App Brewery bootcamp on Udemy. She uses image literals but those seem to have been deprecated on newer versions of Xcode.

I get the error: Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage??' to type 'UIImage?' Whenever I try to use `diceArray.randomElement()`

However, `diceArray[Int.random(in:0...5]` seems to work fine. My suspicion is maybe to use .randomElement() I need to use `imageView` but new to Swift so not sure if this is correct or what the difference even is. Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
      @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            
            
           var diceArray = [UIImage(named: "DiceOne"),UIImage(named: "DiceTwo"),UIImage(named: "DiceThree"),UIImage(named:"DiceFour"),UIImage(named:"DiceFive"),UIImage(named:"DiceSix")]
           
            diceImageView1.image = diceArray.randomElement()
            diceImageView2.image = diceArray[Int.random(in: 0...5)]
          
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sh_Khan pointed out, you have an array of Optionals since `UIImage.named(_:)` returns an Optional.

I would suggest adding a call to compactMap at the end of your code that declares your array of images:

```
var diceArray = [UIImage(named: "DiceOne")…].compactMap { $0 }
```

That will make `diceArray` an array of `UIImage`s instead of `Optional(UIImage)` (and strip out any failed attempts to load images.)

### Edit:

Alexander pointed out in the comments that this might be a case where force-unwrapping is a good thing.

If you write the code like this:

```
var diceArray = [
    UIImage(named: "DiceOne")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceTwo")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceThree")!,    
    UIImage(named:"DiceFour")!,    
    UIImage(named:"DiceFive")!,
    UIImage(named:"DiceSix")!
]
```

That version will also create an array of non-optional `UIImage`s. If you mis-name any of the images, or there are other problems, the above code will crash immediately. Once it runs without crashing, though, you can be confident that the images will continue to load.

The version with `compactMap()` would simply create an array when any misnamed images were missing.

Comment: Agree, this implementation is great

Comment: I think force unwrapping is highly preferable here. If you misspelled the image name, it’s better to notice and fix it than to have an image just be silently absent.

Comment: @Alexander, fair point. I'll add that as an option as well.

Comment: thank you guys for such a thorough reply. It does look like force unwrapping is better here but I hadn't covered compactMaps yet so it was good for me to learn about it. Thanks again!

Comment: `compactMap` is a “high order function” that applies a transform to the members of a collection, and then strips out any nil objects before returning a transformed collection. It is indeed quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

`UIImage(named:`  initializer returns `UIImage?` and `randomElement` returns an Optional so it's `??` , you can force it

```
diceImageView1.image = diceArray.randomElement()!
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. What does one question mark vs two question marks mean? (I'm referencing the ? in UIImage? and ?? after you said "randomElement returns an Optional so it's ??")

Comment: A question mark after a type creates a variable that is an Optional of that type. (That can contain a value or not.) A question mark in a function call is called “optional chaining.” It tells the compiler “If this variable contains an object, invoke one of it’s methods. If not, stop. Two question marks is called a “nil coalescing operator.” It says “evaluate the optional variable on the left. If it’s not nil, do nothing. If it’s nil, substitute the value after the `??`.”

Comment: I would suggest downloading Apple’s Swift iBook and really studying the section on optionals and all the different ways of dealing with them. It’s critical to being able to work in Swift.

Comment: Took a quick look at the iBook. Looks helpful, will definitely check that section out. Thank you for that tip and your explanations, @DuncanC!